Polar decomposition of $\sqrt{\sqrt{\rho} \sigma \sqrt{\rho}}$
By polar decomposition of a square invertible matrix $A$, I understand $A = |A| U$ for some unitary matrix $U$, where $|A| = \sqrt{A^\dagger A}$ with $\dagger$ denoting the conjugate-transpose operation. Now in Nielsen and Chuang's book, chapter 9, I find the following statement

$\dots$,apply the polar decomposition $\sqrt{\sqrt{\rho} \sigma \sqrt{\rho}} = \sqrt{\rho}\sqrt{\sigma} U$, $\dots$

But following the definition, if $A= \sqrt{\sqrt{\rho} \sigma \sqrt{\rho}}$, then $A^\dagger A = (\sqrt{\rho} \sigma \sqrt{\rho})^\dagger \sqrt{\rho} \sigma \sqrt{\rho} = \sqrt{\rho} \sigma \rho \sqrt{\rho}$, and the polar decomposition should read
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{\rho} \sigma \sqrt{\rho}} = \sqrt{\sqrt{\rho} \sigma \rho \sqrt{\rho}} U.$$
This seems different from what is mentioned. I'm surely missing something here!

related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4664/55

also you're missing a square root in the post I think. Your $A$ isn't compatible with your expression for $A^\dagger A$. The point here is to observe $|\sqrt\rho\sqrt\sigma|=\sqrt{\sqrt\sigma \rho \sqrt\sigma}$

Note that $\sqrt\rho\sigma\sqrt\rho$ is already positive semidefinite$^1$, so defining $A=\sqrt\rho\sigma\sqrt\rho$ leads to $|A|=A$. Not interesting.
Instead, let's define $A:=\sqrt\sigma\sqrt\rho$. Then $A^\dagger A=\sqrt\rho\sigma\sqrt\rho$ and $|A|=\sqrt{A^\dagger A}=\sqrt{\sqrt\rho\sigma\sqrt\rho}$. Thus, $|\sqrt\sigma\sqrt\rho|=\sqrt{\sqrt\rho\sigma\sqrt\rho}$ and by polar decomposition $\sqrt{\sqrt\rho\sigma\sqrt\rho}=\sqrt\sigma\sqrt\rho U$ for some unitary $U$.

$^1$ To see this just consider a quadratic form with it.


Thanks @Adam, I think with your definition of $A$, the polar decomposition should read $\sqrt{\sigma}\sqrt{\rho} = \sqrt{ \sqrt{\rho} \sigma \sqrt{\rho}} U$, not the other way around.

You hit the equation with the inverse of the unitary part of the polar decomposition to get what you have in Nielsen and Chuang.
